# Deleting the state from mapwithState in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, stateful

I am intending to implement a spark streaming application based on session of some network data. I am using a state-full programming for RDDs.

Due to huge number of records and keys, I need to delete  some states in my mapwithsate function after some condition in my streaming logic is abided!

I wonder why how to do this, I know in sate specification, there is a time out but this is not the functionality I am looking for rather I should delete the state from the memory to alleviate the amount of memory which my streaming application consumes.

for example below is a sample satefull function

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[Int],state:     State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
val output = (key, sum)
state.update(sum)
Some(output)
}
```

I wonder how to delete a state for a key if some condition is applied so releasing the memory my streaming application needs..

Answer (score 1):

You can call state.remove() function based on some condition. See the api at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/State.html